# Java Get Properties from XML File and Create Object

Tags: java, xml, oop

I have a xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ActionDictionary>
    <action id="100000">
        <actiontype>BackupFile</actiontype>
        <filename>translated.properties</filename>
    </action>

    <action id="100001">
        <actiontype>ModifyPropertiesFile</actiontype>
        <filename>translated.properties</filename>
    </action>


    <action id="100002">
        <actiontype>DeployDomain</actiontype>
        <hostname>localhost</hostname>
        <port>8000</port>
        <domainhome>c:\\domain</domainhome>
    </action>   
</ActionDictionary>
```

When executing, an  action id will be give to the program (ex: id="10000"). The program will use the id to get all properties of the action tag in the xml file above which have the same id with the given id. These properties could be put to somewhere like an object. Then I could use this object to continue the other business.

How could I implement this in Java?

Comment: I have modified it. As I know Java have JAXB technology for parsing XML to Object and vice versa. But JAXB could not be used in this case, so I would lilke to know is there any solution for my problem :)

Comment: are there any other restriction on XML-parsing?

Comment: @MartinFrank my xml file contain many type of action and the properties of each action is very diffirent with the other it means each `action tag` will have its own Ojbect desgin so JAXB could not be be applied.

Comment: if you are not able to use any XML-parser then you have to parse the document manually -- i really advise you to **NOT do it manually!** (use a file reader and read line by line until you find a matching entry)

Answer (score 0):

@Hoang, you can use javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement and javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType of Javax api.

I would suggest to have a read through api docs [Javax API](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/)